# Jataka Story Request: Mindfulness, Radiant Complexion and Grass Simile

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, the-buddha, texts, jataka

I'm looking for a story in the Jataka wherein the Buddha talks about mindfulness and the importance of not living in the past or future. He compares the mind living in the past or future to grass that has been cut off from its root. When that happens the grass will dry out and the same thing happens to the mind that does not live in the present moment.

It was asked how monks who only eat 1 meal a day or sometimes don't eat at all can still retain such radiant complexion. That's where the Buddha taught the above grass simile.

[*Here's a link to the video where Bhante talks about it. It's mentioned at 6:45 into the video.*](https://youtu.be/QEbbpUs94bA?t=405)

Can anyone help me find the Jataka story?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a fun search, thank you.

I found it in [538. Muga-Pakkha Jātaka](https://suttacentral.net/ja538/en/cowell-rouse), quoted below.

> At that moment the queen Candadevi, surrounded by the royal ladies,
> came up, and after clasping her dear son’s feet and saluting him, sat
> on one side with her eyes full of tears. The king said to her, “Lady,
> see what thy son’s food is,” and put some of the leaves into her hand
> and also gave a little to the other ladies, who took it, saying, “O my
> lord, dost thou indeed eat such food? thou endurest great hardship,”
> and sat down. Then the king said, “O my son, this appears wonderful to
> me,” and he spoke a stanza:
>
> > “Most strange indeed it seems to me that thou thus left alone
> > Livest on such mean food and yet thy colour is not gone.”
>
> The prince thus replied:
>
> > “Upon this bed of leaves strewn here I lie indeed alone,—
> > A pleasant bed it is and so my colour is not gone;
> >
> > Girt with their swords no cruel guards stand sternly looking on,—
> > A pleasant bed it is and so my colour is not gone;
> >
> > Over the past I do not mourn nor for the future weep,—
> > I meet the present as it comes, and so my colour keep.
> >
> > Mourning about the hopeless past or some uncertain future need,—
> > This dries a young man’s vigour up as when you cut a fresh green reed.”

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the exact same simile. But there are two similar similes.

The first is about the contemplative being withdrawn or not being withdrawn from sensuality in body and mind.

> "Then these three similes — spontaneous, never before heard — appeared
> to me. Suppose there were a wet, sappy piece of timber lying in the
> water, and a man were to come along with an upper fire-stick,
> thinking, 'I'll light a fire. I'll produce heat.' Now what do you
> think? Would he be able to light a fire and produce heat by rubbing
> the upper fire-stick in the wet, sappy timber lying in the water?"
>
> "No, Master Gotama. Why is that? Because the timber is wet & sappy,
> and besides it is lying in the water. Eventually the man would reap
> only his share of weariness & disappointment."
>
> "So it is with any brahman or contemplative who does not live
> withdrawn from sensuality in body & mind, and whose desire,
> infatuation, urge, thirst, & fever for sensuality is not relinquished
> & stilled within him: Whether or not he feels painful, racking,
> piercing feelings due to his striving [for Awakening], he is incapable
> of knowledge, vision, & unexcelled self-awakening. This was the first
> simile — spontaneous, never before heard — that appeared to me.
>
> "Then a second simile — spontaneous, never before heard — appeared to
> me. Suppose there were a wet, sappy piece of timber lying on land far
> from water, and a man were to come along with an upper fire-stick,
> thinking, 'I'll light a fire. I'll produce heat.' Now what do you
> think? Would he be able to light a fire and produce heat by rubbing
> the upper fire-stick in the wet, sappy timber lying on land far from
> water?"
>
> "No, Master Gotama. Why is that? Because the timber is wet & sappy,
> even though it is lying on land far from water. Eventually the man
> would reap only his share of weariness & disappointment."
>
> "So it is with any brahman or contemplative who lives withdrawn from
> sensuality in body only, but whose desire, infatuation, urge, thirst,
> & fever for sensuality is not relinquished & stilled within him:
> Whether or not he feels painful, racking, piercing feelings due to his
> striving, he is incapable of knowledge, vision, & unexcelled
> self-awakening. This was the second simile — spontaneous, never before
> heard — that appeared to me.
>
> "Then a third simile — spontaneous, never before heard — appeared to
> me. Suppose there were a dry, sapless piece of timber lying on land
> far from water, and a man were to come along with an upper fire-stick,
> thinking, 'I'll light a fire. I'll produce heat.' Now what do you
> think? Would he be able to light a fire and produce heat by rubbing
> the upper fire-stick in the dry, sapless timber lying on land?"
>
> "Yes, Master Gotama. Why is that? Because the timber is dry & sapless,
> and besides it is lying on land far from water."
>
> "So it is with any brahman or contemplative who lives withdrawn from
> sensuality in body & mind, and whose desire, infatuation, urge,
> thirst, & fever for sensuality is relinquished & stilled within him:
> Whether or not he feels painful, racking, piercing feelings due to his
> striving, he is capable of knowledge, vision, & unexcelled
> self-awakening. This was the third simile — spontaneous, never before
> heard — that appeared to me.
> [Maha Saccaka Sutta (MN 36)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.036.than.html)

The second is about the mind being sluggish or not sluggish, agitated or not agitated, and which are the appropriate enlightenment factors for it depending on situation.

> "At such times, monks, as the mind is sluggish, that is the wrong time
> to cultivate the enlightenment-factor of tranquillity, the
> enlightenment-factor of concentration, the enlightenment-factor of
> equanimity. What is the reason? A sluggish mind is hard to arouse by
> these factors.
>
> "Suppose a man wants to make a small fire blaze. If he heaps wet
> grass, wet cow-dung and wet sticks on it, if he exposes it to wind and
> rain and sprinkles it with dust, can he make that small fire blaze?"
>
> "No indeed, Lord."
>
> "Just so, when the mind is sluggish it is the wrong time to cultivate
> the enlightenment-factors of tranquillity, concentration and
> equanimity, because a sluggish mind is hard to arouse through these
> factors.
>
> "But, monks, when the mind is sluggish, that is the right time to
> cultivate the enlightenment-factor of investigation-of-states, the
> enlightenment-factor of energy, the enlightenment-factor of rapture.
> What is the reason? A sluggish mind is easy to arouse by these
> factors.
>
> "Suppose a man wants to make a small fire blaze. If he heaps dry
> grass, dry cow-dung and dry sticks on it, blows on it with his mouth,
> and does not sprinkle it with dust, can he make that fire blaze?"
>
> "Yes indeed, Lord."
>
> "... a sluggish mind is easy to arouse through these factors.
>
> "Monks, when the mind is agitated, that is the wrong time to cultivate
> the enlightenment-factors of investigation-of-states, of energy, of
> rapture. Why? An agitated mind is hard to calm through these factors.
>
> "Suppose a man wants to put a big fire out. If he heaps dry cow-dung
> and dry sticks on it, blow on it with his mouth, and does not sprinkle
> it with dust, can he put that fire out?"
>
> "No indeed, Lord."
>
> "... an agitated mind is not easy to calm through these factors.
>
> "When the mind is agitated, that is the right time to cultivate the
> enlightenment-factors of tranquillity, concentration, equanimity. Why?
> Because an agitated mind is easy to calm through these factors.
>
> "Suppose a man wants to put out a big fire. If he heaps wet grass, wet
> cow-dung, wet sticks on it and if he exposes it to wind and rain, if
> he sprinkles it with dust, can he put that big fire out?"
>
> "Yes indeed, Lord."
>
> "Just so, monks, when the mind is agitated, that is the right time to
> cultivate the enlightenment-factors of tranquillity, concentration,
> equanimity. An agitated mind is easy to calm through these factors.
>
> "But as for mindfulness, monks, I declare that it is always useful."
> [Aggi Sutta (SN 46.53)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn46/sn46.053.wlsh.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.